# iOS voiceOver/accessibility foreign words pronuncation

Tags: ios, voiceover, language-detection

Some of the texts I assign to accessibilityLabel(s) in my iOS app contain "mixed language".

For example, in German the text would be "Bier und guter Sound". The word "Sound" spoken with German VoiceOver language doesn't make sense (it should say "saund", but sounds like "sund").

Is there a way to give voice over information about a word's language?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, assign an attributed string to the `accessibilityLabel` (even though it is of type String, it will accept AttributedString), and use `UIAccessibilitySpeechAttributeLanguage` to set language information for parts of the string that differ from the UI language. E.g. in your case, you would set range (start=15, length=5) to have `UIAccessibilitySpeechAttributeLanguage` with value "en" (or try "en-US" or "en_US" if that does not work, not sure right now which one it will accept, it should be the BCP 47 language code according to the docs).

If you are using Swift, then its type safety will not allow you to assign an `AttributedString` to property `accessibilityLabel` of type `String`, you can work around this by using `label.setValue(attributedString, forKey: "accessibilityLabel")`. A bit of a hack (or workaround), but works.

Comment: my devices general language is set to english. using your suggestion to hint the system for a german word contained in the english text is pronounced correct. using the rotor in-app to set accessibility language to german and hinting an english word inside german text doesn't... looks like a forgotten feature in iOS... thanks though!

Comment: forget about my previous comment, problem solved. but i should add that it's important to call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setAccessibilityLanguage:@"de"]` somewhere.

Comment: If you set your VoiceOver language rotor to any explicit language (i.e. to any other value that the "default language, <your UI language name>", you recognize explicit language setting by VO not saying the words "default language" for them in rotor), then VO ignores language attributes provided by the developer and simply uses the language you set to pronounce everything.

Comment: i see, makes sense. the fact that accessibilityLabel is of type NSString is kind of wrong though. this triggers a warning even if it is possible to assign an NSAttributedString. thanks for your help!